# my app crash in uikit ，only happen on IPhone X and above exception name NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uikit, iphone-x

Failed to load bounding path bitmap data from the asset manager for asset name: BoundingPathBitmap-1125x2436-375x812-3.00x

The crash happen on the viewcontroller contain UIScrollView When open it，and only happens with the iPhone X and above

We develop app UI use storyboard

```
    0 CoreFoundation    ___exceptionPreprocess + 228
    1 libobjc.A.dylib   objc_exception_throw + 56
    2 CoreFoundation    +[_CFXNotificationTokenRegistration keyCallbacks]
    3 Foundation    -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 112
    4 UIKitCore -[_UIScreenBezierBoundingPathUtilities _loadBitmapForScreen:type:] + 1124
    5 UIKitCore -[_UIScreenBezierBoundingPathUtilities initWithScreen:] + 144
    6 UIKitCore +[_UIScreenBoundingPathUtilities boundingPathUtilitiesForScreen:] + 108
    7 UIKitCore -[UIScreen _boundingPathUtilities] + 56
    8 UIKitCore -[UIWindow _boundingPath] + 168
    9 UIKitCore -[UIView(UIViewBoundingPathSupportInternal) _effectiveBoundingPathAndBoundingPathView:] + 256
    10 UIKitCore    -[UIView(UIViewBoundingPathSupport) _inscribedRectInBoundingPathByInsettingRect:onEdges:withOptions:] + 88
    11 UIKitCore    -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _baseInsetsForTrailingEdgeAccessoryWithBoundingPathEdgesToUse:safeAreaInsets:bounds:scale:accessoryWidth:additionalInsetFromEdge:] + 180
    12 UIKitCore    -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _baseInsetsForAccessoryOnEdge:hasCustomClientInsets:accessorySize:additionalInsetFromEdge:] + 1388
    13 UIKitCore    -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _effectiveVerticalScrollIndicatorInsets] + 152
    14 UIKitCore    -[UIScrollView _layoutVerticalScrollIndicatorWithBounds:effectiveInset:contentOffset:fraction:additionalInset:cornerAdjust:showing:recalcSize:] + 252
    15 UIKitCore    -[UIScrollView _adjustScrollerIndicators:alwaysShowingThem:] + 1040
    16 UIKitCore    -[UIScrollView _updateForChangedScrollIndicatorRelatedInsets] + 132
    17 UIKitCore    __UIScrollViewAdjustForOverlayInsetsChangeIfNecessary + 512
    18 UIKitCore    -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) setSafeAreaInsets:] + 312
    19 UIKitCore    -[UIView(Geometry) _applyISEngineLayoutValuesToBoundsOnly:] + 1288
    20 UIKitCore    -[UIView(Geometry) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 124
    21 UIKitCore    -[UIScrollView(_UIOldConstraintBasedLayoutSupport) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 52
    22 CoreFoundation   -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 464
    23 UIKitCore    -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 156
    24 UIKitCore    -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _is_layout] + 152
    25 UIKitCore    -[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 988
    26 UIKitCore    -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1380
    27 QuartzCore   0x00000001ca79e000 + 1309564
    28 QuartzCore   0x00000001ca79e000 + 1329972
    29 QuartzCore   0x00000001ca79e000 + 669080
    30 QuartzCore   0x00000001ca79e000 + 859848
    31 QuartzCore   0x00000001ca79e000 + 863536
    32 CoreFoundation   ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
    33 CoreFoundation   ___CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
    34 CoreFoundation   ___CFRunLoopRun + 1264
    35 CoreFoundation   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
    36 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal + 100
    37 UIKitCore    UIApplicationMain + 212
    38 live main (main.mm:23)
    39 libdyld.dylib    0x00000001c5d2a000 + 2996
```

hope someone could give me some advice, thanks

Answer (score 9):

It just happened with my app .. Fixed ,
`Delete the app` and `restart Simulator` ..
^ `command + shift + K` to clean build folder

Answer (score 3):

The same crash also happened in my app.

When I turned off the 'Show Horizontal Indicator' and 'Show Vertical Indicator' on the storyboard, the crash no longer occurred.