# Crash when running React Native app on iPhone 15 Pro Max simulator

Tags: ios, typescript, react-native, splash-screen

`Thread 1: "Failed to load bounding path bitmap data from the asset manager for asset name: BoundingPathBitmap-1290x2796-430x932-3.00x"` and 1290x2796 happens to be the resolution for the iPhone 15 Pro Max. It would appear something has to be added for its particular screen resolution. But I cannot find any files with `BoundingPathBitmap` in the filename.

There is this: [my app crash in uikit ，only happen on IPhone X and above exception name NSInternalInconsistencyException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55627370/my-app-crash-in-uikit-only-happen-on-iphone-x-and-above-exception-name-nsintern)

But it is old and the problem does not occur on iPhone X, so it must be a different issue. It is not React Native and my question is. The solutions are also unclear.

I tried upgrading `react-native-splash-screen` and that did not help. I cannot find out why it is trying to load this asset and where it should be defined.

Edit: It happens even on a newly-generated unmodified react-native project. Does this mean react-native has a bug?

Edit1: Opened bug report here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/39438

Comment: I am not sure, but is this above mentioned ending from the file name: "1290x2796-430x932-3.00x" belongs to your image file name? The 3.00x regarding the dot could be mismatch the file format maybe. Try to rename it without the dot inside.

Comment: @lortschi What image? But the hypothetical files related to this name cannot be found anywhere, I grepped through node_modules and even the simulator installations for them and there is no sign of them. The breakpoint on this crash gives no information as it only traces down to some assembly code. The deepest it goes in source code is `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`.

Comment: Started seeing this suddenly today too with the 15 Pro Max simulator with no changes present in my branch to cause it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that re-downloading Xcode 15 fixed it. I do not know if it was corrupt or just a pre-release version with a bug.